# How do I send a canvas.captureStream to video on safari?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, html5-canvas, html5-video

It seems that the `canvas.captureStream` on Safari browser gives some problem.
This is the logic: the browser load an image, the image is drawn into a canvas using `.drawImage`, then the `outputVideo.srcOject` is set with the `canvas.captureStream`.
Everything works on chrome and firefox, in Safari (even I have no errors) the sample image is not shown.
Here is the code to reproduce the error:

```js
let img_source = document.getElementById('img_source');
let canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');
let video = document.getElementById('videoOutput');
img_source.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', function(){

  canvas1.width = img_source.naturalWidth;
  canvas1.height = img_source.naturalHeight;

  canvas1.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
  let ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
  ctx1.drawImage(img_source, 0, 0);
  let stream = canvas1.captureStream();
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function(){
    this.play();
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #ccc;
}
canvas, img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="start">start</button>
<img id="img_source" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/sample-stamp-grunge-texture-vector-260nw-1389188336.jpg" />
<canvas id="canvas1" ></canvas>

<video id="videoOutput" muted playsinline loop></video>
```